# Нужна ли запятая перед ЧТО: "Всё что хочу — это..."?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед что?

> Всё что хочу - это...
>   Всё что мне нужно - это...

Answer (score 4):

Конечно, нужна, так как со слова "что" начинается придаточное предложение "что хочу"

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! Ах, Виктор, как не хочется ставить! (нутро протестует)))) 
Особенно здесь: Всё что мне нужно – …

Comment: Кстати, придаточное предложение нужно тоже закрыть запятой: "Все, что хочу, - это..."